# Reset content every month

Tags: php

I currently have a code that resets every Saturdays, which the content is being displayed the entire week until next Saturday. I'd like to use the same approach for monthly basis (display the content for the entire month until next for a new content) and I can't get it to work. The weekly code is this:

```
$dayoftheweek = date("l");
$todayis = date('Y-m-d');

if($dayoftheweek == 'Saturday') { // The day it updates
    $dateUpdate = $todayis; 
} else {  
    $dateUpdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "$todayis last Saturday" )); // The day it updates
}

// Content to display
switch($dateUpdate) {
    case '2020-05-02':
        // Content here
    break;
    case '2020-05-09':
        // Content here
    break;
    default:
        // Display content when ran out of rounds
}
```

I'm following the same code pattern for the monthly basis, am I doing something wrong for the strtotime or something? Here's the monthly code that I have right now:

```
$firstofmonth = date("d");
$thisday = date('Y-m-d');

if($firstofmonth == '01') {
    $MonthlyUpdate = $thisday;
} else {
    $MonthlyUpdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first day of -1 month"));
}
```

The contents I'm supposed to have for monthly basis is not being displayed with the code above when I set the case date to '2020-05-01'. Again, am I doing something wrong for the strtotime or something? Or is there a better approach? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to be a really strange approach. This should be done by using a database.

Comment: Why? databases are for tabular data structures.

Comment: _Why? databases are for tabular data structures...._ Exactly, you've answered your own question @dehart

Comment: I don't understand, why a database? The OP talks about behaviour based on a date. @B001ᛦ

Comment: Content to display should be stored in the database being linked to the corresponding date unless you don't want to be modifying the code every day/week/month/year. Writing code is not just about understanding the correct syntax but also scalability and maintainability @dehart

Comment: Thx @B001ᛦ  I agree, however this could be done using any IO device not just a database. There is a great talk by Robert C. Martin called "The Principles of Clean Architecture" on YouTube I think you would enjoy. skip to `42:45` for the database part. https://youtu.be/o_TH-Y78tt4

Comment: Thank you for the reference @dehart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the day (`d`) variable out and only check month + year:

```
switch(date('Y-m')) {
    case '2020-05':
        // Content here
    break;
    case '2020-06':
        // Content here
    break;
    default:
        // Display content when ran out of rounds
}
```